# How to check if the device has biometrics

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am new to Xamarin forms and coding in general, I want to check if the device has biometrics as soon as the app is launched. I came across this video that shows how to do it using a button, I wanted to use it as soon as I open the app. can you help?

```
btnFPLogin.Clicked += FingerPrint;

    private async void FingerPrint(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var result = await CrossFingerprint.Current.IsAvailableAsync(true);
                Plugin.Fingerprint.Abstractions.FingerprintAuthenticationResult auth;
                if (result)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var res = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Success", "Your data are saved", "Ok", "Cancel");
                        auth = await CrossFingerprint.Current.AuthenticateAsync("Authenticate access");
                        if (auth.Authenticated)
                        {
                            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Results are here", "Valid fingerprint found", "Ok");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Results are here", "Invalid fingerprint", "Ok");
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("permission to use FaceID", "We need permission to use FaceID", "Ok");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: If you are using MAUI, I would try https://github.com/FreakyAli/Plugin.Maui.Biometric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've answered your own question.  To check if a device supports biometric login, use the CrossFingerprint plugin

```
var result = await CrossFingerprint.Current.IsAvailableAsync(true);
```

if you want to check this on app launch, put it in the `OnStart` method of the `App` class